# Drawing tree in latex with horizontal bars

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I want to draw the following tree in latex. But, I don't know how to do it. Over searching on internet I found other kinds of tree but not this kind. I will be glad if someone can help me drawing this. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `forest` package and the `edges` library you can use the option `forked edges`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
forked edges
[Constraint
    [Holonomic
        [Rhenomic][Scleronomic]
    ]
    [Non-holonomic]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Equivalently, you can place `forked edge` in a `for tree`, which also allows you to control `fork sep` and many other options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
forked edge, fork sep=2.5mm, s sep=5mm
}
[Constraint
    [Holonomic
        [Rhenomic][Scleronomic]
    ]
    [Non-holonomic]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```